# How do I code a Python script for running a browser video in loop at playback speed more than 2x?

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

I'm learning Python scripts, but I thought of experimenting with something for a browser video. I'm trying to make a Python script that will run that particular browser video in a loop for as many times I want and in 4x playback speed.

As I searched many tools appeared like Selenium with Python.
But still, I'm looking for some help through this.

Comment: have you setup selenium on your system?

Comment: Not yet, since I was first looking for the solution or a road map to how should I continue on things.

Comment: I'll do it now. But we can proceed

Comment: @AnkitKashyap - you are expressly going against the guidelines of this site. This isn't a place to connect with people outside of this site, via email or any other medium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any browser automation tool to do this.
Here is the solution for your various use case using selenium :

### YouTube

##### Imports and page load

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

s = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-YO1MRGl3M')
```

##### Utility to wait for Ad

The below code waits until the Ad completes. Obviously you can do this using selenium's `wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element`. Let me know if you need that code. Here we are doing this using javascript. Its better you do this every x period(say).

```
waitForAd  = '''if (document.querySelector("div.ad-showing"))
                    return true
                return false
             '''
while(driver.execute_script(waitForAd)): pass
```

##### Play on Loop

To play the video in loop, you can set the video object property.

```
playInLoop = '''const video = document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")[0]
                    video.loop = true
             '''
driver.execute_script(playInLoop)
```

To play on loop on some condition you can check you can write a javascript function that plays the video on loop until the variable play is set, when you want the video to stop playing again, you can set the variable play as false.

##### Change playback speed

Here we have passed 4, you can pass anything here

```
driver.execute_script('''document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 4;''')
```

Obviously all the above script can be formatted on user input by using python's format string.

### Vimeo

The above example was for a youtube video. Here is how you can do the same for a vimeo embedded video.

##### Get Element

```
getVideo = '''vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]'''
driver.execute_script(getVideo)
```

##### Play on loop

Again, the loop attribute can be set to false on user input by making an execute_script request again.

```
playOnLoop = '''vid.loop = true'''
driver.execute_script(playOnLoop)
```

##### Change playback speed

Here we have set it to 3, you can set anywhere between the range

```
playbackRate= '''vid.playbackRate = 3'''
driver.execute_script(playbackRate)
```

##### Pausing the video

```
pause = '''vid.pause()'''
driver.execute_script(pause)
```

Vimeo provides multiple API's for a video element that can satisfy all your project requirement. Try exploring the [`documentation`](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/basics) for it.

Comment: I'm confused in the first part of Vimeo itself. Which drivers and imports are needed to be added in there for the vimeo video ?

Comment: And also I just tried to use test the youtube example as well to check if the selenium setup is working or not, but an error occurred.

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chrome.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home`

Comment: Have you downloaded the chrome driver? you need to supply the path of chrome driver in the path

Comment: All the steps that are mentioned on the selenium website, I have followed through. But still, the error came. I sent you the code on your Gmail.
Whereas, the code of chrome path seems this way 
`chrome_path = r"E:\DEBUGS\Visual_Studio\PRactice\chromedriver.exe"`

Comment: Also, I doubt that the above code will work because it doesn't have the WAIT element in it. Since the video will play for a few seconds at least, so the code needs to wait till that time and after then only it has to again play the video.

Comment: You need to set the attribute loop = True, if you want the video to be played again. I don't understand why you are using Wait for it